# C# Socket Send Picture JPEG

Tags: c#, sockets, jpeg, mirc

So I have found here in stackoverflow One code for sending through sockets a binary file, an image.. So i used it for test to my Project

```
private void send_ss()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int sent;
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 306);

        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            server.Connect(ipep);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.");
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }


        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Windows\\Web\\Wallpaper\\Theme2\\img7.jpg");

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        // Save to memory using the Jpeg format
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // read to end
        byte[] bmpBytes = ms.ToArray();
        bmp.Dispose();
        ms.Close();

        sent = SendVarData(server, bmpBytes);

        //Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting from server...");
        server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        server.Close();
    }
    private static int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int size = data.Length;
        int dataleft = size;
        int sent;

        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
        datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        sent = s.Send(datasize);

        while (total < size)
        {
            sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
            total += sent;
            dataleft -= sent;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

so i tried to send this picture on one of my Listening Sockets in Port 306 (listened with m IRC)

```
on *:socklisten:ac_img:{
  var %p = $ticks $+ $time(hhnnss) $+ $ctime
  sockaccept ac_img_ $+ %p
  echo -s [] Image Connection Established On -> ac_img_ $+ %p
}
on *:sockread:ac_img_*:{
  sockread &picture 
  bwrite $qt($mIRCdir $+ $sockname $+ .jpg) -1 -1 &picture 
}
```

So i'm getting files like ac_img_2920385501147471360792067.jpg and so on. Same size with the original BUT the images just not appearing , so i opened Both files with word pad and they were a bit different... dunno why...[image: ScreenShot]

So any ideas why i'm facing this issue? i mean... I'm taking every single data from my socket and saving them to the file? Maybe a corrupt on file read through c#?

Comment: Have you seen this question reference sending a XML file as binary data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692181/xml-over-tcp-socket/14719589#14719589? Perhaps a similar solution replacing *.xml with *.jpg will work for you.

Comment: This may not answer your question - but you could make your code alot more resource friendly by simply reading the jpg file data (`File.ReadAllBytes()`) instead of converting to bitmap and then back to jpg

Comment: So I tried your way C.Evenhuis

      `sent = SendVarData(server, ReadContentFromFile("C:\\Windows\\Web\\Wallpaper\\Theme2\\img7.jpg"));

 public static byte[] ReadContentFromFile(String filePath)
        {
            return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }`

still same.. so the issue must be on Sendvardata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is different because you read it, parse it into a `Bitmap` and reencode it. The wordpad screenshot shows that both are JPEG's but with different metadata (for example "adobe" missing").

Just use `File.ReadAllBytes` or other lossless methods to read the image.

The sending code looks sound. Not sure why you're looping. Sending never does partial IOs AFAIK on blocking sockets.

Comment: I used file.readallbytes and fixed this issue, but anotherone came up.. I don't know why... But i'm recieving some extra bytes..

my mIRC appears:

     `[Data] Total Size 158116` but my C# appears `158112
`

Comment: @Devian - the 4 extra bytes being received are surely because you're sending 4 extra bytes in the form of the `datasize` (a 4 byte integer) which is sent before the image data.

Comment: true damn sorry , after 4k lines of code you are a bit of braindead sorry.